# Is there a straightforward procedure for creating a boot menu that can load isos on UEFI usb devices?

Tags: windows, windows-8.1, uefi

I have seen exactly one tool that claims to do this, and the documentation is an ungodly mess. Has anybody succeeded?

At this pont Id settle for just a serious documentation on uefi boot device partitioning under win8.1.

Comment: What exactly would that boot menu accomplish? Which operating systems are to booted from where?

Comment: @DanielB I want to have a win8 install iso and a disk imager iso on one drive

Answer (score 0):

I know of two ways to do this; however, one way is rather crude and I know little about the other (I'm not even 100% positive it can work):

- You can create a USB flash drive with [rEFInd](http://www.rodsbooks.com/refind/) on it and with rEFInd's ISO-9660 EFI driver installed. You can then create two more partitions and write the image files for your two CD/DVD images *directly* to the partitions. For instance, in Linux, you'd do something like `dd if=foo.iso of=/dev/sdb2` to write `foo.iso` to the second partition on the `/dev/sdb` USB flash drive. You should then be able to boot the image file from the partition. One caveat is that I can't guarantee that the software on the image file written to a partition would work correctly. (If not, it might work if you copied it on a file level to a FAT partition.)
- [GRUB 2](http://www.gnu.org/software/grub/) has the ability to treat image files like disks. [This question and answer](https://askubuntu.com/questions/141940/how-to-boot-live-iso-images) provide some details about how to do this. I've never used this feature, though, so I can't say from personal experience what its capabilities are.